# Relacionando modelos con laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Cual de estas convenciones es la recomendada por los desarrolladores de laravel.

he visto que al hacer relaciones en un modelo se escribe por ejemplo:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

Sin embargo tambien he visto esto:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

Aunque las dos relacionan con el mismo modelo , cual es la recomendada de la casa. (No me refiero al número de parámetros sino la convención en si misma)

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

es bastante simple:

1. **User::class** devuelve el nombre completo de la clase
2. mientras que en **'App\user'** estas pasando clase FQN

ahora bien cual es las mas combeniente seria **'App\user'** porque no requieres del contexto **use**

Comment: Tal cual, de esta forma te ahorrarias una linea mas de codigo.

Answer (score 1):

No he encontrado ninguna sugerencia en la documentacion de laravel sobre cual convencion usar, sin embargo, en todos los ejemplos se utiliza la segunda forma

> The phone method should call the hasOne method and return its result:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

Fuente: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships